# How to get Redis Hash Length?

Tags: redis

I store objects using hashes on Redis and I would like to calculate the length of these Hashes from Redis point of view.

You can do this easily for strings using `STRLEN`.

But I simply can not find a suitable command for the hash data type in the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands). It seems to be the same thing for lists or sets.

Basically, the only solution that I found is to get the whole hash with `HGETALL`  and to calculate the length on client size.

Is is something completely out of the box ?

If I'm wrong, please do not hesite to explain  me why or give me relevant links/posts/SO questions.

**Edit** :

[HLEN](http://redis.io/commands/hlen) is not a solution because it "Returns the number of fields contained in the hash".
I want to calculate this size for Capacity Planning & Active Monitoring on Redis database.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? Is it to estimate memory usage on redis? Or do you need to implement a particular feature? There are ways to find out the `length of hash from redis' point of view`, but it may or may not be useful depending on your use case.

Comment: @Cybermaxs What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the length as disk space you can use [DEBUG OBJECT](http://redis.io/commands/debug-object) as it returns several information items for each key.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:50001> hset myhash field1 'hello'
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:50001> hset myhash field2 'world'
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:50001> DEBUG OBJECT myhash
Value at:0x7fb8de4ad590 refcount:1 encoding:zipmap serializedlength:31 lru:696871 lru_seconds_idle:0
```

Hope it helps

Comment: So how many bytes does that object take up? I don't understand `serialized length` 31?

Comment: You didn't actually answer OP's question. How many bytes?

Answer (score 38):

Just use [HLEN](http://redis.io/commands/hlen).

```
redis> HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET myhash field2 "World"
(integer) 1
redis> HLEN myhash
(integer) 2
```

**EDIT:** The question was clarified to be that the OP wants the size on disk of a hash for active monitoring. In that case, I'd definitely go with a Lua script that calculates the size of a hash on your server and returns the value back to you. **Do not** use HGETALL if you're expecting big hashes, because you'll need to transfer that entire hash from your server to your client computer, and that's going to become your bottleneck really quickly. Just doing this calculation on the Redis server with Lua means you get to just transfer an int of the number of bytes of your network instead of possibly mb of data for your entire hash.

Comment: As I said before, HLEN returns only the number of fields for a Hash

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic you never mentioned HLEN anywhere in your post. And the length of a hash is the number of fields (keys). What length are you referring to if not that? In any other language, when you do something like len(hash), that's what you expect to have returned.

Comment: Oh it's true. HLEN "Returns the number of fields contained in the hash stored at key" ; not the length or if your prefer the size of the whole hash.

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here. Redis has keys in a database that point to particular data structures. In your case, a Redis key points to your hash (which is composed of many hash keys that point at values). `HLEN` does give you the length of the hash (the number of keys in the hash). It still sounds to me like this is what you're asking for. In case what you're actually asking for is the size on disk on the hash, I've edited my answer above.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you want to do with the length of the hash.

If you want the length to do some diagnostics or monitoring, like finding the memory consumed, then I'd suggest you do it offline using a tool like [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) (disclaimer: I am the author of this tool). The csv dump file will get you statistics about each key - including total size, total memory consumed and so on.

But if you want the size to implement some application feature, then there isn't a readymade solution. HGETALL plus client size calculation of the length is the way to go. You can perhaps optimize by writing a lua script so that the length calculation happens on the redis server itself.

Comment: Downvoter - can you please leave a comment why this was downvoted? I don't mind the downvote, but would love to know what I missed or stated incorrectly :)

Comment: I didn't downvoted you but upvoted for your great tool redis-rdb-tools.

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan I downvoted because the obvious answer to "how to get redis hash length" is HLEN, but apparently the OP meant something other than the "length" of the hash in his question, so your answer is actually good. I'd remove the downvote, but SO won't let me anymore unless you edit your answer somehow. If you do, I'd be happy to remove it :).

Comment: @Eli No worries, I don't mind it all. Thanks for leaving a comment, this is the first time someone took the effort to explain a down vote!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MEMORY USAGE](https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage) command.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset user:1000 username antirez birthyear 1977 verified 1 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> memory usage user:1000 
(integer) 110
```

As you are using this for capacity planing, this command has the advantage of including any administrative overhead that redis adds on top of the size of your data itself.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET "" ""
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY USAGE ""
(integer) 46
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your best bet would be to use [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) when you come across a hash to get the fields and sum up [HSTRLEN](https://redis.io/commands/hstrlen) for each of them.